# Observable collection change is not updated on UI from background but a normal property gets notification

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have two classes

```
public class ConccClass<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
}
```

and

```
public class TestTherad: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    { get {
        return name;
    }
        set
        {
            if (value != name)
            {
                name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    //// the notification implemented fully here
}
```

Now I have created a collection of 'ConccClass' in my view model and binded it with datagrid on xaml in view.

Question
When I add an item on a background thread simply without any dispacther it does not reflect in datagrid. means no item added. Todo this I have to add the item in Dispatcher. BeginInvoke. Which make sense to me.

But to update the Name of any Item I dont need dispatcher.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.Coll.Add(new TestTherad())); // **Works well**
                    //this.Coll.Add(new TestTherad()); // **does not work at all.**
                    this.Coll[0].Name = r.Next().ToString(); // ** without dispatcher works well.**
                }
            }
        });
```

Why such behavior?

Comment: Which version of .Net?

Comment: Using dotPeek, inside `INotifyPropertyChanged` there is `event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`. Taking a look at `PropertyChangedEventHandler` shows that it's a delegate with the following attribute `[HostProtection(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, SharedState = true)]`. I wonder if [SharedState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.hostprotectionattribute.sharedstate(v=vs.110).aspx) is allowing the delegate to run successfully on the main thread without the need to invoke.

Comment: @OmegaMan - it is VS 2012.

Comment: What is Coll? the datagrid or the ConccClass<T> instance? Show the XAML code for the Binding as I think the issue is in there. And the code behind.

Answer (score 5):

The following is a short explanation:

You probably have an UI element binded to the observable collection. When you add an element to the observable collection, the UI updates to reflect changes. However, the only thread allowed to make changes to UI is the main thread.

So when you add an item to the observable collection using a background thread, the UI tries to update using the background thread, which is not allowed to make changes to UI, and an exception is thrown.

I am pretty sure that this line should throw an exception: //this.Coll.Add(new TestTherad());. Try debugging inside the task block.

When you use the dispatcher, you are making the update using the main thread, and for that reason it works.

The update to properties work, because you are just raising an event. The framework should listen for that event and make sure to dispatch it to the main thread automatically.

Comment: I tested that even if I bound the Name property with ContentControl it works well ( no need of text block) without Dispatcher. I still believe that there is a hidden reason behind this behavior. Ofcourse I know that one property is updating the UI another not. But why?

Comment: @DJ couldnt understand your comment. "The update to properties work, because you are just raising an event. The framework should listen for that event and make sure to dispatch it to the main thread automatically." is not the answer?

Comment: sorry for late reply.  But in both the cases the event is raised in one collection change event which is also listen on UI. in another it is also event. Also both are binded on   UI.   How it is different?

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to avoid these exceptions is to use the BindableCollection from Caliburn.Micro.
This is a ObservableCollection that will automatically dispatch the CollectionChanged events to the Main Thread.

Only Use the BindableCollection in your ViewModels because the CollectionChanged events will be on the Main Thread and for performance reasons you would like to do the most of the coding on a background Thread.

Comment: BindableCollection is good stuff. It's a good option unless you plan to write an observablecollection with blocking like this: http://xcalibursystems.com/2014/02/making-a-better-observablecollection-part-2-cross-threading/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I am looking for my answer.

Comment: `BindableCollection` is broken, and it perpetuates the lie that it is somehow safe to modify a list on one thread while it is UI-bound on another.  There are conditions besides explicit change notifications which may cause a collection to be requeried, potentially during an update, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I used extensively threading and Binding in XAML and it is safe and works very well the problem is the confusion between INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged ObservableCollection fires the second not the first.

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid This is not a subjective thing; it is provably unsafe to modify a collection on a background thread while it is bound to your UI thread (unless you are using the new collection synchronization binding features of .NET 4.5).  The fact that you have not observed any issues does not make it safe; it makes you lucky, or it means your particular usage patterns have a low risk of concurrency hazards.

Comment: @MikeStrobel re-riding my answer I notice that it can look like I was implying that it was thread safe I did not meant that, what I was implying is that updating a collection in a threaded manner fires the correct events for the binded element to update correctly without need for Dispatcher.Invoke.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the previous comments have already answered this, however, this should summarise.  Prior to .NET 4.5, you could only call updates on an ObservablCollection on the UI thread.  This is being achieved via the call to Dispatcher.Invoke.  The call to updated the objects name does not affect the collections events etc., only the object.  Updating the objects properties should also ideally be done only on the UI thread, however, depending upon how the property is bound, you can sometimes get away with updating these properties from a non-ui thread.  As has been mentioned, this will vary depending which version of .Net is being used.

Answer (score 0):

At Github you'll find a small helper class called AsyncObservableCollection :[Github](https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/10023516) It is a very thin wrapper around an OberserableCollection. It takes over all the threading issues you mention. You create the collection from your ui thread and then use the collection from any thread you want.